# How to define multiple routes to single component?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I use Vue 2 in my project.
I have those routes:

```
 const routes = [
  {
    path: "/suites",
    component: Home,
  },
  {
    path: "*",
    component: LandingPage,
  },
];
```

I need to add one additional route:

```
www.mysite.com/?number=xxxxxx
```

on this route, the Home component should be displayed.

I tried:

```
  {
    path: {"/suites","?number=xxxxxx"}
    component: Home,
  }
```

but the attitude above doesn't work.
Any idea how can I make both routes
(the "xxxxxx" is some number that can be changed)

```
        "?number=xxxxxx"      
        "/suites"
```

To open the component?

Comment: `?number` is a query param on `/`, so use `{path: '/',alias: '/suites',component: Home},` then do a check on `this.$route.path` if its `/` then do a check on `this.$route.query.number` to get your xxxxxx value

Answer (score 0):

The path attribute should be a single string, not an array.
You need to define two routes. If you prefer not to duplicate your code, you could do something like this:

```js
{
  ...(['/suites', '/'].map(path => ({
    path,
    component: Home,
  }),
}
```

To get the number parameter in your vue component, you should be able to fetch it with the following code:

```js
this.$route.query.number
```

See https://router.vuejs.org/api/#the-route-object

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the post. How do I make xxxxx dynamic?

Comment: I edited my answer to better  answer to your question :)

Comment: No, it's not clear how I use map route and how I use numb in route.

Comment: You can't specify the query parameter you will receive in your route. Alternatively, you can do the following: 
`'/:number'` and get it like that: `this.$route.params.number`

Comment: Solar, I don't need to get the number parameter. I just need to configure how to navigate to Home component in case if I have this route format : ?number=xxxxx.
xxxxx is any number.

Comment: In this case, to specify your route, you only need to define it as : `'/'`, because you don't have to/ can't specify query parameters in vuerouter.

Answer (score 0):

In the `Home` component, setup a watcher on `$route.query` to observe changes to the query parameter, redirecting to the landing page when the `number` query is not found:

```js
// Home.vue
export default {
  watch: {
    "$route.query"(query) {
      if (!query.number) {
        this.$router.replace({ name: "landing" })
      }
    }
  }
}
```

In the router config, use a regular expression within the `path` string (passed to [`path-to-regexp`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/path-to-regexp)) so that both `/` and `/suites` resolve to the `Home` component:

```js
const routes = [
  {
    path: "/(suites)?",  // "suites" is optional
    component: Home,
  },
  {
    path: "*",
    name: "landing",
    component: LandingPage,
  },
]
```

[demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/redirect-on-query-parameter-d7yx3?file=/src/views/Home.vue)